# Bundler could not find compatible versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, gemfile

I have multiple gems failing on my app. My bundler is not able to find compatible versions for all. I also do not have a 'Gemfile.lock' and it does not get created on `bundle install`. As follows:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    draper was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)

    jquery-datatables-rails (~> 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.3.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.1)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)

    rails-api was resolved to 0.4.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.2.11)

    ransack was resolved to 1.8.10, which depends on
      actionpack (< 5.2, >= 3.0)

    redis-rails was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
      redis-actionpack (< 6, >= 5.0) was resolved to 5.1.0, which depends on
        actionpack (< 7, >= 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    acts_as_api (= 1.0.1) was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)

    carrierwave (>= 1.0.0.beta, < 2.0) was resolved to 1.3.2, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)

    paperclip (~> 4.3.2) was resolved to 4.3.7, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    activerecord-postgres-hstore was resolved to 0.7.8, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 3.1)

    audited (~> 4.7) was resolved to 4.8.0, which depends on
      activerecord (< 5.3, >= 4.0)

    rails (= 4.1.6) was resolved to 4.1.6, which depends on
      activerecord (= 4.1.6)
```

I am trying it again with the following specifications and getting the same result.
bundler: 1.16.6
rails: 4.1.6
ruby: 2.3.8
ubuntu: 18.04

I can see my gems when I do `gem list` but it still says bundler is not able to find anything for rails 4.1.6.

Comment: What is your Ruby version? What is your bundler version?

Comment: You just need to downgrade ransack? Everything else seems like it is conforming to your "rails = 4.1.6" requirement

Comment: My ruby version is 2.7.1 and bundler version is 1.17.3

Comment: Trying with ruby 2.3.8 and bundler 1.16.6 and rails 4.1.6 but still same issue. Is it possible that the machine is blocking bundler or anything to search and get the required gems?

Answer (score 0):

Add `source` in your Gemfile like below:

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

delete everything form your `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install`

[image]

Comment: I already have the ```source```  in my Gemfile and I do not have a ```Gemfile.lock```